# Error:(54, 13) Failed to resolve: com.afollestad:material-dialogs:0.6.0

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I bought a source code and I'm getting this error:

> Error:(54, 13) Failed to resolve: 
>   com.afollestad:material-dialogs:0.6.0 
>   href="openFile:C:/Users/abdelmohcen/Desktop/spatullr-recipes-app-for-android/app/build.gradle">Show
>   in File
> Show in 
>   Project Structure dialog

Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Here the build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.pongodev.recipesapp"
    minSdkVersion 11
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 5
    versionName "3.0.3"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

// Main libraries, you always need this libraries in your project. do not remove them.

// Important library to create material design. do not remove this.
compile project(':materialDesign')

// Library to create tabbar

// Library to create ripple effect. work together with materialDesign library.

// Library to create rounded, circle, and any shape image.

// Library load lazy images.

// Library to create simple list.

// Library to create complex clickable list.

// Library to create material dialog.

// Library to create animation imageview.

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
compile 'com.jpardogo.materialtabstrip:library:1.0.6'
compile 'com.github.traex.rippleeffect:library:1.2.2'
compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:1.4.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.0'
compile 'com.afollestad:material-dialogs:0.6.0'
compile 'com.flaviofaria:kenburnsview:1.0.5'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.4.0'
}
```

Comment: your question is not clear. Try to put some code and error logs

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please visit the Help Center to read about [how to ask questions effectively](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). Your question currently contains too little information to give you any meaningful answer. Since you say you bought this source code, ask the person or company that you bought it from how to work with it.

Comment: i edited the topic with the codes

Comment: You may want to remove this line... `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'` You likely do not need **all** the google play services since you have included the ones you do want at the bottom (GCM, Ads, Auth)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That version **(0.6.0)** is no longer published.

Use the latest stable version:

```
dependencies {
    // ... other dependencies here
    compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.0.1'
}
```

Also, since you are using the support libraries v24 you have to use **api 24 to compile**.

```
compileSdkVersion 24
```

Answer (score 0):

Or You Can Replace your dependency with this :

```
compile('com.github.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.8.5.2@aar') {
transitive = true }
```